# Sharepoint list entry & flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

SharePoint list entry disappears after flow is completed.

It is not going pass 'when an item is created'. SharePoint and list ID are correct. Checked the obvious.

It has been running ok and after adding delays to the flow, I have an anomaly.

Can anyone assist?

[image: flow details]

Answer (score 0):

I had a filter on the sharepoint list hence I could not see new entries.

My apologies for the time wasted.

Love to all